# page contains broken hyperlinks

Tags: seo

i got the SEO error "page containd broken hyperlink". i test the URL its working fine then also it will give the same error. please give me solution for this error.

thanks

shankar

Answer (score 4):

Your page probably contains a broken hyperlink.

The small print: That is, not your page, but either one of the pages it links to is defunct, or one of the links to these pages is ill formatted.

Comment: In other words, check if the hyperlink in your page is correct.

Comment: I apologise, I felt I had to verbosify it.

Answer (score 0):

Yor're going to have to give us more info. Can you post a link, or give us the HTML in full (if its not too large).

What SEO tool are you using (maybe we can check it too)?

Can you give us the exact error message along with the reference to the link it thinks that is failing?

Have you clicked on the hyperlink itself?

Finally, how can you be sure it is the link that you are checking? Maybe another one is failing?